# Where to store the .mpd file on django to play on a dash player?

Tags: python, django, ffmpeg, mpeg-dash, mp4box

I am trying to build a video player on django. I am using MPEG-DASH for adaptive streaming of the video file. I have chosen a sample video in the beginning. Then, using ffmpeg commands, I have encoded the video into 240p, 360p, 480p and 720p videos. Also have encoded audio separately.

Then, using mp4box, I have generated the .mpd file. I have read that mpd files cannot be run from the local file system and need to be hosted on a server. I have a dash player setup as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>player</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.dashjs.org/latest/dash.all.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    video {
       width: 640px;
       height: 360px;
    }
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
       <video data-dashjs-player autoplay src="https://dash.akamaized.net/envivio/EnvivioDash3/manifest.mpd" controls></video>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The url in the src field is a random manifest file that i used to test the player out. It works fine.

Then, on my django project, I have created a media folder which stores the media files uploaded via a form(root included in `settings.py`). 
My question is where do i store the video, audio and .mpd file so that i can play them using the html code which resides in the templates folder. I have tried using the media url of .mpd file in the source but I am unable to play the video.

Here is the generated mpd file for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- MPD file Generated with GPAC version 0.7.0-rev0-gbd5c9af-master  at 2018-12-21T18:45:32.091Z-->
<MPD xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" minBufferTime="PT1.500S" type="static" mediaPresentationDuration="PT0H1M9.869S" maxSegmentDuration="PT0H0M9.985S" profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-on-demand:2011,http://dashif.org/guidelines/dash264">
 <ProgramInformation moreInformationURL="http://gpac.io">
  <Title>BBB</Title>
 </ProgramInformation>

 <Period duration="PT0H1M9.869S">
  <AdaptationSet segmentAlignment="true" lang="und" subsegmentAlignment="true" subsegmentStartsWithSAP="1">
   <Representation id="1" mimeType="audio/mp4" codecs="mp4a.40.2" audioSamplingRate="44100" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="130920">
    <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:23003:3:audio_channel_configuration:2011" value="2"/>
    <BaseURL>sample_audio_dashinit.mp4</BaseURL>
    <SegmentBase indexRangeExact="true" indexRange="902-1017">
      <Initialization range="0-901"/>
    </SegmentBase>
   </Representation>
  </AdaptationSet>
  <AdaptationSet segmentAlignment="true" group="1" maxWidth="426" maxHeight="240" maxFrameRate="30" par="426:240" lang="und" subsegmentAlignment="true" subsegmentStartsWithSAP="1">
   <Representation id="2" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.640015" width="426" height="240" frameRate="30" sar="1:1" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="590708">
    <BaseURL>sample_video_240_dashinit.mp4</BaseURL>
    <SegmentBase indexRangeExact="true" indexRange="914-1053">
      <Initialization range="0-913"/>
    </SegmentBase>
   </Representation>
  </AdaptationSet>
  <AdaptationSet segmentAlignment="true" group="1" maxWidth="640" maxHeight="480" maxFrameRate="30" par="4:3" lang="und" subsegmentAlignment="true" subsegmentStartsWithSAP="1">
   <Representation id="3" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.64001E" width="480" height="360" frameRate="30" sar="1:1" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="883873">
    <BaseURL>sample_video_360_dashinit.mp4</BaseURL>
    <SegmentBase indexRangeExact="true" indexRange="914-1053">
      <Initialization range="0-913"/>
    </SegmentBase>
   </Representation>
   <Representation id="4" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.64001E" width="640" height="480" frameRate="30" sar="1:1" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="1188712">
    <BaseURL>sample_video_480_dashinit.mp4</BaseURL>
    <SegmentBase indexRangeExact="true" indexRange="913-1052">
      <Initialization range="0-912"/>
    </SegmentBase>
   </Representation>
  </AdaptationSet>
  <AdaptationSet segmentAlignment="true" group="1" maxWidth="1280" maxHeight="720" maxFrameRate="30" par="16:9" lang="und" subsegmentAlignment="true" subsegmentStartsWithSAP="1">
   <Representation id="5" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.64001F" width="1280" height="720" frameRate="30" sar="1:1" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="2365717">
    <BaseURL>sample_video_720_dashinit.mp4</BaseURL>
    <SegmentBase indexRangeExact="true" indexRange="914-1053">
      <Initialization range="0-913"/>
    </SegmentBase>
   </Representation>
  </AdaptationSet>
 </Period>
</MPD>
```

Comment: if you dont mind .. what happened to your project? Did you succeed what you try to achieve?